# Ссылка для поделиться в одноклассники?

Tags: php, laravel, odnoklassniki-api

Ссылка для поделиться в одноклассники?
Подскажите, как правильно сделать ссылку , чтобы поделить постом в одноклассники?

пробую так, не работает

```
<li class="odnoklassniki">
<a href="https://connect.ok.ru/offer?url={{$article->slug}}/{{$comment['id']}}">
<svg><use xlink:href="#odnoklassniki"></use></svg>
</a>
</li>
```

Comment: А в результате построения страницы, во что это "превращается": `{{$article->slug}}/{{$comment['id']}}`? `так, не работает` - конкретнее опишите, пожалуйста.

Answer (score 0):

Пример: [Поделиться в ОК](https://connect.ok.ru/dk?st.cmd=WidgetSharePreview&st.shareUrl=https%3A%2F%2Fmetanit.com%2F)

Ваша ссылка или битая или фишинговая,  разные сайты проверки дают разные результаты))

А если подробнее - зайдите, например, на https://metanit.com/ и нажмите поделиться на ОК. Там будет рабочая ссылка на вашу страницу и выдумывать ничего не придется.
В таких ссылках адрес отправителя обязателен. В вашей ссылке такого адреса нет, но есть подозрительные API.

P.S. Ну для оформления ссылки можно воспользоваться блогом, например.
Я вот на Либре сделал и подсветку ссылки и подсказочку к ней.